# Who can visit the island?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I visited the island for the first time today in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*. Later my sister (a resident in my town) went to the dock, but Kapp'n wasn't there. Are there restrictions on who may go to the island, or is it only one trip a day?

Comment: It's definitely not only one trip a day, as I've gone several times in one day.

Comment: Is your sister a resident of the same town you're mayor of or did she connect to you through local WiFi to try to go? Maybe the requirements are different between local and WiFi players who attempt to visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is the exact requirements:

1. Get your house built.
2. Pay off your mortgage.
3. Wait a day for Tortimer to show up and give you the invite to the island.
4. The day after that you can go to the island.

Answer (score 2):

After paying off the first dues of the campsite to an upgraded constructed home, Isabelle will inform the player on the following day that the previous Mayor will want to present himself after a long retirement. Tortimer will address the PC Villager that he in-list your name on the roster for Kappn's boat ride.

There are also restrictions on who may come in from Wi-Fi, being only friends or those with your code added. This outlook changes once you become a pledged member of CLUB TORTIMER sold in-store at the island at times presented by the shop.

Each round about trip costs 1000 bells and consists of this single charge, allowing anyone from a Wi-Fi group to ride for free. Once one wants to travel back the requirements are all characters must go back to their seatings to deploy back to town.

Answer (score 0):

You may only go to the island if you've paid off your 'mortgage' to Nook.

More information [here](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Island).

Comment: I hadn't paid my mortgage off and was able to go to a friend's island.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe the source is flawed. Could you access your own island as well, or only your friend's?

Comment: Only my friend's. I don't even have the island unlocked in my town. She talked to Kapp'n, paid the fare, and I rode with.

Comment: Don't just link to something on SE. [Explain it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Yes anyone can go to the island. The mayor of the town will be able to go after he or she has paid the mortgage of the house at least once. The other players have to do the same thing. Although it is different if you are in someone else's town. Even if you don't meet the requirements for your town as long as the other person who's town your in does reach the requirements then anyone that person invites will be able to visit the island with them. hope this helps!