# How do I plant flowers in the beginning of the game?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In various guides I see the same advice:

> The [Gardening] store opens five days after the player has created their town. The player must also pull weeds and plant flowers a combined total of 30 times.

But the gardening store is where I buy flower seeds so... how can I plant flowers before it opens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plant flowers simply by picking up flowers that have grown on their own with the Y button, moving to a new location, and going into the inventory and planting them from there.

Comment: Does this count for the Gardening Store though?

Comment: Yes, it's the only way to do it at that point other than buying flowers from a friend's store. The point of it is so that it shows that you have an interest in the flowers in the first place.

Comment: @parashep: Well, just pulling 30 weeds works too, right?

Comment: @Ullallulloo of course. that would probably just take much longer in real life time to actually grow the weeds.

Answer (score 1):

As another suggestion in addition to the current answers, a perhaps more productive method to achieve this goal is to complete the [requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/120645/19096) to unlock the island. This can be achieved as early as day four ([source](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Island#Tortimer_Island)) and will allow you access to several mini-games that generate temporary locations with flowers already planted. You can pick up these flowers and they will remain in your inventory after the mini-game has ended.  You can store the flowers in the box near Leilani, which holds up to 40 items.  When you leave the island, you will be able to collect any items in the box located on the dock.

Collecting flowers from the island will allow you to plant new flowers instead of tricking the game counter by planting existing flowers, and to begin any landscaping goals (or progress towards particular badges) earlier.  It is a useful source of flowers even after the gardening shop opens, as you can collect many more flowers on the island than you can each day in the shop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to purchase flowers at a friend's gardening store, so that's a second way if you have friends further along than you.