# Can you swim to the island on Animal Crossing New Leaf

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Can you *swim* to the island on New Leaf? Is It possible to? I don't know! All I saw was ropes! Can you cut the rope or not?

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot swim to the Island in Animal Crossing: New Leaf. The only way to get to the Island is by booking a ride with Kapp'n for 1,000 Bells. The exact requirements for unlocking the Island can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/120645/8350). They are:

> 1. Get your house built.
> 2. Pay off your mortgage.
> 3. Wait a day for Tortimer to show up and give you the invite to the island.
> 4. The day after that you can go to the island.

Comment: How does HE get through. AND I KNOW!

Comment: @user68528 They probably just lift the ropes up?

Comment: _Through the magic of television..._

Comment: _I_ _know_ _that_... lifting is not possible!

Comment: @animalcrossingrocks24 For you, but not for an NPC. If you're asking us for the way in which Kappa gets out then that's impossible for us to answer because there is no way to know, nor does it really matter. Paths which are blocked off to the player but which NPC can go through have existed since the earliest days of gaming, it's nothing new. The reason for it is that devs often need to restrict the gamers playing area and walls are how that's done, but don't always need to restrict the NPCs.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot swim to the island. You must meet the requirements to unlock it, then once you meet all requirements, after Isabelle loads up your game, Tortimer will talk to you and tell you to meet him at the dock on the beach. When you meet with him, he tells you he has retired and is on this island. He invites you to come, and starting the next day, Kappn will be at your dock in his boat, asking for only 1,000 bells to take you to the island. You can play games and buy island exclusive furniture. When you want to leave, you just talk to the girl at the desk, and tell her you want to go home. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can't swim to the island.

> Before heading to the island, you must pay your 39,800-bell mortgage to trigger access to the ferry service from the dock of your town. Tortimer, sporting tropical wear, will appear "under the spotlight" in the "dark room" as you load your game. That day, speak to him at the dock.
>
> The following day, you can travel to the resort island (AKA Tortimer's Island)! At the dock, speak to Kapp'n to go to the resort island. The trip costs 1,000 bells, and Kapp'n will serenade you twice during the voyage (with sometimes bizarre lyrics). When he starts to sing, you can tap the "A" or "B" buttons or the touch screen to speed the voyage and immediately arrive. He doesn't seem offended. If multiple players are making the trip, Kapp'n will specifically ask whether you all want to listen to his serenade.

[image: Island]

[Source](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Island)

Answer (score 0):

sorry but you have to unlock the island and ride a boat with kapp'n. To unlock the island get 10,000 bells and talk to tom nook while his store is open. Then pay off your next home loan in the post office ATM which is in the bottom left hand corner. After you pay off that the next day Mayor Tortimer will say he retired and went to an island. He will give you an invite to his tropical paradise. Once you start the game go to the dock and talk to Mayor Tortimer. The next day Kapp'n will be there asking you if you want to go to the island for 1,000 bells. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot swim to Tortimer Island. According to Animal Crossing wiki,

> The player must complete several tasks before the option is made available but it can be reached as early as day four. When the player has upgraded from the tent to the house, and then upgraded once after that, Isabelle will introduce Tortimer the next day when the player starts the game. He will ask the player to meet him by the dock. Once at the dock, Tortimer will tell the player about the island. However, it is not until the next day that Kapp'n will appear with his new motorized boat at the dock, which will be ready to take the player to the island for a fee of 1,000 Bells per round-trip.

Comment: What does this answer provide that the existing answers do not?

Comment: ?????????????????????????????

Comment: I don't see any information in this answer that was not already stated in Wipqozn's answer.

Comment: ok i saw ur(your) comment